# Set theory-Equivalence classes

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If R is an equivalence relation in X, and if x is in X, the equivalence class of x with respect to R is the set of all those elements y in X for which x R y.

Is x the first element of every ordered pair?
And y the second?

Isn’t x always in X?

Thanks

Comment: If $R$ is a equivalence relation then is simetric

Comment: If X = {1,2,3} and R = X x X then the equivalence class is X?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the ordered pair you refer to is a set $A \in X \times X$ where $\times$ denotes the *Cartesian Product.*

In general, for given $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$ and relation $R \subseteq X \times Y$, if $(x,y) \in R$, it is written $xRy$. So, to answer your question, $x$ is the first element of the ordered pair, and $y$ the second, for a general relation. For example, if $R$ is actually the inequality $<$, then $2<3$ is not equal to $3<2$. Thus, this distinction is needed.

In this case, however, since it is an equivalence relation, we know that $xRy=yRx$, as per one of the requirements to be considered an equivalence relation. Or, that both $(x,y)$ and $(y,x)$ are in $R$, so a distinction isn't needed in an equivalence relation.

Comment: If X = {1,2,3} and R = X x X, isn’t the equivalence class {{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3}}?

Comment: First, note that there can't be duplicates in a set, so here that duplicate is {1,2,3}, instead the set would be {{1,2,3}}. Next, the cartesian product just grabs the set of combinations of elements of one set with another into ordered pairs.. So here, X x X={(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)...(3,3)}. Finally, the equivalence class with respect to an equivalence relation R, also depends on an element of X, let it be a. The equivalence class of a is then all y such that yRa. So, there isn't a sense in which you say something is THE equivalence class, alone. So, no, that isn't 'the' equivalence class.

Comment: So, to look at this, if R=X x X, then we are, say 1 in X, looking for all y such that yR1. But, R consists of all those and only those of all possible elements of a given set mashed with other elements of a different set, into an ordered pair. So, that means y can be 1, 2, or 3 as our set X={1,2,3}, which y is a part of to be a relation(per the definition). Clearly, then, {1,2,3} is our equivalence class. Not {{1,2,3}}.(This distinction between sets of set is important, {{x}}=/={x})

Comment: Okay so does {{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3}}={{1,2,3}}? Thanks

Comment: @Paul yes, naming the same set thrice does not matter. There is but one class and it's the whole set, as every point is equivalent to any other point.